# How to change the QR Code version from 3 to 10 in ZXing

Tags: c#, zxing, qr-code

I have created an application which generates me a qr code image with ZXing library, but it uses version 3 for the qr code and I want to know if I can change it to version 10...I am new to the ZXing library...

This is the code:

```
public void CreateQRImage(string inputData)
{
    if (radioRH.Checked)
    {
        if (inputData.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data must not be empty.");
        }

        BarcodeWriter qrcoder = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H,
                Height = 250,
                Width = 250
            }
        };

        string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + inputData + ".png";

        Image image;
        String data = inputData;
        var result = qrcoder.Write(inputData);
        image = new Bitmap(result);
        image.Save(tempFileName);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempFileName);

        var textRes = qrcoder.Write(inputData);

        int textWidth = 230, textHeight = 20;
        // creating new bitmap having imcreased width
        var img = new Bitmap(textRes.Width + textWidth, textRes.Height);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 14))
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        using (var bgBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
        using (var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near })
        {
            // filling background with white color
            g.FillRectangle(bgBrush, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
            // drawing the generated image over new one
            g.DrawImage(textRes, new Point(0, 0));
            // drawing text
            g.DrawString(inputData, font, brush, textRes.Width, (result.Height - textHeight) / 2, format);
        }

        img.Save(tempFileName);
    }
```

I want the QR Code image to be changed from this (version 3)
[image]

To this (version 10)
[image]

Comment: Why? The size depends on the data you put into the code. So just write more and you will get a bigger code.

Comment: I need this for my practice project. Can't I create the version 10 for 15 characters text?

Comment: No, it needs more data in it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, that's incorrect. [Here's an example](https://i.imgur.com/3WrMXhd.png) of two different versions (10 and 1) with the same data.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had the same problem.

I was asked by my company to generate version 4 QR codes (33 by 33), but Zxing was defaulting to a lower version.

This is not documented hardly at all on the net, but there is a way to force Zxing to generate a specific version of QR code.  In your code sample, just add "QrVersion = 10" to the format options:

```
    BarcodeWriter qrcoder = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = new ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions
        {
            ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H,
            Height = 250,
            Width = 250,
            QrVersion = 10
        }
    };
```

This will produce a version-10 QR code.

**Note: If you set a low QrVersion number (for example, 4), then try to put lots of data into the QR code, an error will be thrown.